# how to I merge 2 VMware disks in to a single one , on ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, vmware, lvm

I have installed an Ubuntu server on a VMWare workstation with a space of 20GB storage as seen below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNCrV.png

After the installation I've attached another 40GB worth storage to the existing Ubuntu server installation (seen below):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLpV.png
Now I want to add this 40GB to my / (root) directory it mean's I want that my / directory became to 60G , like it will be resize from 20G to 60G (20G + 40G), i don't know what should i do, can any body help me ?

, my df -h result shows;

```
root@Userver:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        18G  900M   16G   6% /
udev            990M  4.0K  990M   1% /dev
tmpfs           400M  308K  399M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            999M     0  999M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
root@Userver:~#
```

It must be 60G !

I have no graphic mode, then i can't use Gparted tools, i'm just have ssh access !

Did i must using lvm partition ?

I don't installed  VMware tools on my ubuntu, did i must to install it ?

Finally on Ubuntu command line , what should i do ?
please help me step by step